# Netlify: This site can’t be reached - DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: netlify

I am a newbie web developer and I just finished my MERN Stack project. I am trying to deploy it via Heroku as the server handler and at Netlify for my frontend.

In actuality, my website is already up but the problem that I'm having is that I cannot access it on my computer. I can however access it on my mobile phone and some of my friends was actually able to see it on their unit. They already tested it and the frontend is working with the backend successfully.

When I'm trying to access my website on my computer, it just says that I can't access it and says `DNS_PROBE_FININSHED_NNXDOMAIN.`

I tried accessing it on 3 browsers namely Firefox, Chrome (in incognito as well), and Edge. I also have nothing on my console logs. I tried searching the web for answers but I've tried many things but can't seem to resolve this.

Here's the image link for the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Whj.png).

If you have any idea, any help would be much appreciated! Thank you very much!